# No module named 'ray.rllib.agents.registry'

Tags: ray, sumo, rllib

When running the example (examples/train.py singleagent_ring) to test my rllib installation to use flow with SUMO, I am getting the following error:

from ray.rllib.agents.registry import get_agent_class
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ray.rllib.agents.registry'

I am using macOS (M1) and I've already installed all possible ray libraries.

Anyone facing similar issues or has a solution? Or workaround?

I am using macOS (M1) and I've already installed all possible ray libraries.

Anyone facing similar issues or has a solution? Or workaround?

Comment: Maybe you meant `ray.rllib.algorithms.registry`. I think it was renamed sometime ago.

Answer (score 0):

The updated version will look something like this:

```
from ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo import PPO
```

instead of...

```
from ray.rllib.agents.ppo import PPO
```

Source: https://discuss.ray.io/t/ray-rllib-agents-ppo-missing/9904